# multiple selectors using widlcard jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to serialize  using jquery and want to exclude 2 hidden input types from that.

The hidden elements are

```
<input type="hidden" name="hdnScrollPosX" id="hdnScrollPosX" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="hdnScrollPosY" id="hdnScrollPosY" value="" />
```

When I serialize I dont need these elemets to be considered. I am able to exclude one but not 2.

```
$('#frmMain').find('input[name*= hdnScrollPos]').serialize();
```

This will select these 2 elements but I want the NOT of these to exclude them.

I searched but could not find a way to exclude using wildcard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude those elements by using 'not'

```
$('#frmMain').find('input[name*=hdnScrollPos]').not('#hdnScrollPosX,#hdnScrollPosY').serialize();
```

Comment: I am getting blank value now.

Comment: @user3689864 And how looks like the ones you want to include??? Because regarding your posted code, that should work

Comment: hdnScrollPosX=0&hdnScrollPosY=60&prv_m_hdnPostBack=FALSE&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATECONTROLLER=7c6ab2b3-7e87-4a29-945a-2bf17adc72e1&__VIEWSTA......  This is what I get now with out excluding any of these controls. I need a jquery selector which will exclude hdnScrollPosX & hdnScrollPosY while serializing

Comment: @user3689864 Well, then really poorly asked question if you ask me... So try: `$('#frmMain').find(':input').not('input[name*= hdnScrollPos]').serialize();`